# jquery keyboard pause catch

Tags: jquery

Am catching the keyup events which makes calls for each keyup.

```
jQuery('#Search').keyup(function() {

});
```

But i need something like when user continuously types characters and gave a pass at 5th character or in n'th character that time only i want to trigger a ajax call. Here we can use timeout function to catch the event but each keypress will call the timeout function so again the same thing happening

And if user again started typing after a pause then again it will have to trigger a event/ajax call but after a certain pause only.

Here we need to abort the previous events or ajax calls since again user started searching.

So i used `.abort();` function to abort the previous calls.

Is there a better way to catch event at after a certain period of time in jquery. Please advice me,

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to check out these blog posts on a custom hesitate and hoverIntent jQuery event. http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1786-Building-Custom-jQuery-Event-Types-Hesitate-Event.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var search = $('#Search'),
    search_delay = 100; 


search.keyup(function() {
    var request = search.data('request');

    if(request) { // if request is running - abort it
        request.abort(); 
        search.data('request', null);
    }

    clearTimeout(search.data('timer')); // if timer is running - stop it

    search.data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
        // add your ajax call here or pass a reference 
        // to the function that will handle the ajax call
        search.data('request', $.ajax(...)); 
    }, search_delay);

});
```

You can use jQ `data` API to store references to the intrduced in jQuery 1.5 jqXHR object to be able to `abort` the request and to the timer so you can stop the timer with `clearTimeout`