# jQuery blur alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Detect all changes to a <input type=“text”> (immediately) using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery)

I have a textbox which a user enters data and on the onBlur event it does an AJAX request to validate the data they have entered. If it validates then a button becomes enabled. However users are getting confused that they have to tab out or click somewhere on the page for the button to become enabled.

Is there an alternative event or approach to the code I am using?

```
$('.serial').live('blur', function () {

  //Do AJAX to validate

  //If ok enable button
  $('#button').attr("disabled", "");

});
```

Comment: So many duplicates, so little time... ;-) This is probably the best: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery But there are also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539279/using-jquery-how-do-you-detect-if-the-value-of-a-text-input-has-changed-while-t | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/jquery-how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153047/jquery-detect-changed-input-text-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2885716/84539) answer from the link T.J Crowder posted.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    MonitorSerialTextBoxes();

    $('#newSerial').click(function () {

       $.tmpl("productTemplate", mymodel).insertAfter($(".entry").last());
       MonitorSerialTextBoxes();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), maybe [adding a setTimeout for delaying the requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay).

Comment: Can you do a setTimeout for only certain elements ie $('.serial')

Comment: @Jon: sure, see the accepted answer in the second link I provided. The `delay` function is only called for the element to which you attach the keyup event

Answer (score 1):

Try `keyup` - it's fired after each key is pressed.

```
$('.serial').live('keyup', function () {
    //Do AJAX to validate

    //If ok enable button
    $('#button').attr("disabled", "");
});
```

Comment: but not if they paste data into the field

Comment: Yes it does: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/A9WK6/

Comment: KeyUp makes sense, it will just make a lot of AJAX requests

Comment: @Alnitak Ah, I see your point - if they paste with the mouse.

Comment: There used to be a solution with a timer, requesting ajax only if no key was pressed for 0.5 second for instance. Can't find out where I saw this. Edit: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945019/jquery-keyboard-pause-catch

Comment: Looks like @nico might have posted it

Comment: You're right! I didn't read that deep...

Answer (score 1):

Sending AJAX requests on each keystrokes will make huge request queue. You can limit this If the Serial have a fixed number of Characters or it has a fixed pattern then

```
var validate = function(value){
  //Check for number of characters or do regex validate the value
  //If Validated send ajax request otherwise not
}

$('.serial').live('keyup', function(){
  validate(value);
});

$('.serial').live('blur', function () {
  validate(value);
});

//tracking the mouseover on the submit button may also help
//as its common psychology of the users to play with the submit button
//after the entered the data and nothing is happening
```

also disabling the textbox while validating may also help. such that the user can understand that some processing (validation here) is going on. and the need to wait now.